# When a 8-byte block address generation is less than 11 characters. Do you add 1 to be start or end of the block?

Tags: address

When generating a monero address and one of the 8-byte blocks is less than 11 characters, it states I can pad it with the character 1. Do I **always** add 1 to the beginning of the block output or at the end?

**if a particular block converts to <11 characters, the conversion pads it with "1"s (1 is 0 in Base58)**

> Monero base58 is not like Bitcoin base58, bytes are converted in
> 8-byte blocks. The last block can have less than 8 bytes, but at least
> 1 byte. Eight bytes converts to 11 or less Base58 characters; if a
> particular block converts to <11 characters, the conversion pads it
> with "1"s (1 is 0 in Base58). Likewise, the final block can convert to
> 11 or less Base58 digits.
>
> Due to the conditional padding, the 69-byte string, like Monero
> addresses, will always convert to 95 Base58 characters (8 * 11 + 7);
> where 7 is length of the last block of 5 bytes.
>
> The alphabet is composed of 58 characters visually not similar to
> avoid confusion, e.g. both 1 and l are not part of the alphabet
> together, only 1 is present. The full alphabet is composed of:
> 123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz

Address:
43pQ9h9F7KBFgDpFB1aa9ZAvqbxXa7zixfuFAUoybXzbnsy89jVH4YUG8Wwn1BzSFir8WGMkxHpq91XVNhcaaF27UsGFQw

[18, 57, 233, 247, 246, 39, 189, 38] -- Generates: 43pQ9h9F7KB

[87, 190, 79, 202, 198, 114, 137, 252] -- Generates: FgDpFB1aa9Z

[59, 91, 105, 62, 142, 212, 126, 5] -- Generates: AvqbxXa7zix

[4, 2, 134, 215, 55, 25, 186, 141] -- Generates: **fuFAUoybXz** (only 10 characters)

[208, 0, 122, 244, 178, 147, 68, 205] -- Generates: bnsy89jVH4Y

[162, 251, 100, 144, 167, 8, 96, 108] -- Generates: UG8Wwn1BzSF

[250, 47, 237, 93, 107, 240, 113, 30] -- Generates: ir8WGMkxHpq

[47, 226, 16, 79, 77, 51, 197, 105] -- Generates: 91XVNhcaaF2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I always add 1 to the beginning of the block output or at the end?

The <strike>end</strike> start of the block.

After much [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/lyid1o/missing_1_character_in_monero_address_generation/gpuv2j7) with rbrunner on Reddit, it turns out the padding is at the start.

Comment: Thanks! What was the reasoning for the 1 padding character to be in the front vs at the end. The end seems more logical. Also is there an instance where a block can generate only 9 or 8 characters or even less? So I'm guessing it would be padding with 1111...?

Comment: Yeah it was a little rabbit-hole! I believe it can need more than one pad so always pad with 1's to 11 characters per block (except the last which is 7).